# Python regex to find phrases contain exact words

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings and wish to find exact phases.

So far my code finds the month and year only, but the whole phase including “- Recorded” is needed, like “March 2016 - Recorded”.

How can it add on the “- Recorded” to the regex?

```
import re


texts = [

"Shawn Dookhit took annual leave in March 2016 - Recorded The report",
"Soondren Armon took medical leave in February 2017 - Recorded It was in",
"David Padachi took annual leave in May 2016 - Recorded It says",
"Jack Jagoo",
"Devendradutt Ramgolam took medical leave in August 2016 - Recorded Day back",
"Kate Dudhee",
"Vinaye Ramjuttun took annual leave in  - Recorded Answering"

]

regex = re.compile('(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]+)\s+(?P<year>\d{4})\s')     

for t in texts:
    try:
        m = regex.search(t)
        print m.group()
    except:
        print "keyword's not found"
```

Comment: Uhm, add `.*` I'd guess.

Comment: Or `(?:\W+\w+)?`

Comment: Could you please clarify: do you want to only include the text that is exacltly (equals) `- Recorded`? `r'(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]+)\s+(?P<year>\d{4})\s(?:-\s*Recorded)?'`? Or any 1 word after one or more non-word chars (then see my above comment)? Or the rest of the line (see Sebastian's comment)?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, thank you for the help. I want it inclusive. yours (?:\W+\w+) works very well. but (?:-\s*Recorded) gives an SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character  '\xe2' in......

Comment: It is because SO adds garbage chars into the comment texts. Remove them and it will work. So, does that mean there may be words other than `Recorded`? Is the `-` obligatory before that word? Sorry, your question is too unclear.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, a line # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- added to the code makes it work... thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got 2 named groups here: `month` and `year` which takes month and year from your strings. To get `- Recorded` into `recorded` named group you can do this:

```py
regex = re.compile('(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]+)\s+(?P<year>\d{4})\s(?P<recorded>- Recorded)')
```

Or if you can just add `- Recorded` to your regex without named group:

```py
regex = re.compile('(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]+)\s+(?P<year>\d{4})\s- Recorded')
```

Or you can add named group `other` with hyphen and one capitalized word:

```py
regex = re.compile('(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]+)\s+(?P<year>\d{4})\s(?P<other>- [A-Z][a-z]+)')
```

I think first or third option is preferable because you already got named groups. Also i recommend you to use this web site http://pythex.org/, it really helps to construct regex :).

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension with the corrected regex:

```
regex = re.compile('(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]+)\s+(?P<year>\d{4})\s* - Recorded')

matches = [match.groups() for text in texts for match in [regex.search(text)] if match]
print(matches)
# [('March', '2016'), ('February', '2017'), ('May', '2016'), ('August', '2016')]
```